# Please tell me what is the meaning of the Boolean this expression returning? ( entry.target.classlist.toggle.valueof )

Tags: javascript, toggle, intersection-observer, value-of

I want to trigger an if statement when the intersectionObserver API  toggles a class in the DOM Element.
I am just not sure what exactly is the boolean value returned by this expression: -
entry.target.classlist.toggle.valueof;
or entry.target.classlist.toggle.valueof();

```
let intersect = new IntersectionObserver ((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.target.classList.toggle("fix", entry.isIntersecting).valueOf) {
            fixHeader();
        }
        else unFixHeader();
    });
}, {
    rootMargin: "-1%",
    threshold: 1
});
```

Comment: If it is `.valueOf()`, then it makes little sense. If it is `.valueOf` then it also makes little sense and will cause the if-branch to be always entered (because `.valueOf` is a _function_, which is always a truthy value). Where did you get this code from?

Comment: my code. vs code showed valueof as an option so i selected it because seemed like what i needed.

Comment: [`.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) already returns a boolean value. Calling `.valueOf()` on a boolean just returns the boolean value itself so it is completely redundant. Just stick with `entry.target.classList.toggle("fix", entry.isIntersecting)`.

Comment: That made me wonder in what cases will value of will be actually usseful?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is your friend. :-)